# Use ShingleFilter, but considering punctuation

Tags: lucene

I want to shingle my words, but don't want to shingle over any punctuation like commas or dots. How can I achieve that?

My current chain is:

```
TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer(LUCENE_VERSION, new StringReader(input));
tokenStream =  new StandardFilter( LUCENE_VERSION, tokenStream );
tokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(LUCENE_VERSION, tokenStream);
tokenStream = new StopFilter(LUCENE_VERSION, tokenStream, EnglishAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet());
tokenStream = new ShingleFilter( tokenStream, 2 );
```

When I process following sentences:

```
A test sentence, great thing. Considering punctuation would be great, too.
```

the result will be (single words are ignored here):

```
test sentence; sentence great; great thing; thing considering; considering punctuation;
```

But I want following result (single words are ignored here):

```
test sentence; great thing; considering punctuation;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution myself, but I'm pretty sure there is another (more optimized) version through Lucene. However, my solution is to split the string before I feed Lucene with it.

```
for(String part : input.split("\\p{Punct}")) {
    TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer(LUCENE_VERSION, new StringReader(part));
    tokenStream =  new StandardFilter( LUCENE_VERSION, tokenStream );
    tokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(LUCENE_VERSION, tokenStream);
    tokenStream = new StopFilter(LUCENE_VERSION, tokenStream, EnglishAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet());
    tokenStream = new ShingleFilter( tokenStream, 2 );
    // do something with tokenStream...
}
```

If you find another solution, please let me know.

Comment: This seems like a good solution to me (as long as your okay with splitting on hyphens, underscores, etc).  As soon as `StandardTokenizer` is applied, punctuation is lost, so splitting on it before Tokenizing seems like the right idea.  I'm curious about what goes is place of the `// do something with tokenStream...` though.  Are you joining those `TokenStream`s together?

Comment: No, I extract keywords from the input text. So I throw the tokens in HashMaps, and stuff like that. However, would it be possible to join these streams again?

Comment: Ah, I see.  I don't know of any out-of-the-box solution to joining `TokenStream`s, which is largely why I asked.  However, it would be fairly straightforward, I believe, to create a wrapper for a collection of TokenStreams which extends TokenStream itself.